Is Gnang's proof of Graceful Tree Conjecture correct?
Gallian's dynamic survey on graph labeling mentions Gnang's preprints which claim to resolve the graceful tree conjecture. The latest version of this preprint dates 2023 August. Previous version of the preprint goes back to 2018; another related preprint by Gnang and Wass dates 2020.
What is the mathematics community's view of Gnang's preprint?
If it is not deemed correct, has an error been found?

When you update a post, please incorporate the changes directly into the text so that it reads naturally for someone who sees it for the first time. Do not put it after “Update:”, “Edit:”, or a similar note while leaving the original content in place. I took the liberty of removing the speculative thoughts about what is or is not a good sign for the correctness of the paper that were claimed to be retracted in the update.

He also has another preprint about the same purported proof of the same conjecture https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.07614 with 12 revisions

@gexahedron Yes, I have mentioned this in the question. But, this was removed when a moderator edited the question for focus (the edit has really helped with the focus, and I appreciate it). For me, the preprints (dating back to 2018) having no comments from the authors looked like a bad sign; but, this is not a telltale sign.

@CyriacAntony To me it's a bit strange that it was removed, because as far as I understand the approach is the same, both in 1811.07164 and in 2202.03178. What do you mean by "having no comments from the authors"?

I meant no comments as to why they revised it (important since there is large text overlap). But, it is okay if no major changes are there. Still, I did expect some comment about the new and old preprint (e.g. A comment in the old preprint stating that a revised version is available at url ...).

I am not a moderator. And it wasn’t my intention to remove the link to the old preprint (which is indeed relevant) as part of the edit; sorry about that.

Oh wait, I didn’t remove it, did I? The link was not included in any revision of the question, as far as I can tell. But I can as well put it in.

No problem. As I said, I appreciate the edit done. I shall add the link in bracket.

I already added it. So now it is there twice.
